# Symbolicating crash logs in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, logging, crash, xcode7, symbolicate

I have an AppStore build that produced a crash and a crash log. I do not have the original archive (it sits in a different computer) but I do have .app.dSYM and .app files. Following the steps of Xcode 6.x related answers does not help as I cannot locate "symbolicate" in Xcode 7. I am sure I am missing something obvious...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have crashlog file, you can symbolicate it using xcrun atos. Or using the symbolicate file locate in Xcode package.

Comment: I have accepted the answer but would you care to elaborate I I would use xcrun atos?

Comment: There are so many reference of how to use symbolicate file, or how to use xcrun atos (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27323623/1696598 OR http://stackoverflow.com/a/20364864/1696598). I myself prefer using the symbolicate since it's more simple for me. I'll write a bash file, and perform symbolicate all the crash log in a folder, using symbolicate & DSYM.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes the combination of xcrun and dsym seem to be the thing i need (store builds have their symbols stripped).